# Python: regex to match between matches

Tags: python, regex

Text file output has syntax in a form of `word> data <word`, where the need is to remove the brackets. The `data` part can be pretty much anything (and of variable length), including new line, spaces, dots, letters etc. Currently i am using...

```
text = re.sub("(>)(.{1,10})(<)", r"\2", text)
```

...but it has obvious limitations, 1 being length. The reason for not using `*` is because there are some restrictions, namely:

- no other `>` or `<` can be present inside the match except for its boundaries
- only 1 number inside the match can form a pattern of *single* digits, that is `dog> 7 4^ 8 0 . 2 1 6? <cat` & `exam> 1961 5 . 66 9 <ple` shall not match, while `test> 0? <string` or `over> 1980 31, 6 000 <flow` are fine and brackets shall be removed

How can this be approached?

Comment: over> 1980 31, 000 <flow is to long to be a "fine" match - or the {1,10} quantifier just an example?

Comment: The quantifier is just an example. I’m holding it at ten trying to minimize wrong matches. The real length between `><` can be 1 or it can be 71.

Comment: Don't do that, just show more verifiable examples.

Comment: This is the code i’m using. More fine examples, sure: `dot> 15 <net`, `meta> 00 000 : 9614 472 . <post`

Comment: Without regex?  `''.join(''.join(text.split(">")[1:]).split("<")[:-1]).strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the answerers added to their answers after the one edit of the question, i had to post another question to answer that part and actually finish the regexp.

At last, the final code i’m using is this:

[`text = re.sub(r">((?!(?:[^<]*\b\d\b){2})[^><]*)<", r"\1", text)`](http://regex101.com/r/9A9X7C/1)

It allows for only 1 single digit number and no brackets inside the match, but otherwise catches anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
text = re.sub(r">((?:[^<>\d]|\d{2,})*)<", r"\1", text)
```

`(?:[^<>\d]|\d{2,})*` matches either any character except angle brackets or digits (`[^<>\d]`) or any digits as long as there are at least two (`\d{2,}`), repeatedly (`*`).

Comment: Nice! What if 1 (but not 2+) single digit should match, like `test> 0? <string`, but not `exam> 1961 5 . 66 9 <ple`? Just adding `{2,}` after `\d` doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: @Россарх You did not say that in your original question, did you?

Comment: Nope, i actually only understood the need after i ran your regexp as a filter on my files ^^

Comment: Well. My expression captures one alternative. Just add another one. Think about it for a moment.

Comment: Aye, i tried. I have edited the original question to reflect this need and have messaged the other answerer to give a chance to edit that answer as well.